# Element binding function of Jquery not working in angular 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to integrate HTML admin template in angular 7 but It is not able to call .click method of element written in js files
here is complete scenario.

angular.json

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles/materialize.scss",
          "src/styles/style.scss",
          "src/styles/custom/custom.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/js/vendors.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins.js"
        ]
```

Here vendors.min.js file contains jquery.js and material.js
In plugins.js file i have some functions and bindings

header.component.html

```
<li class="hide-on-med-and-down"><a class="waves-effect waves-block waves-light toggle-fullscreen" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">settings_overscan</i></a></li>
```

in plugins.js file i have written below code

```
 function toggleFullScreen() {
  console.log("aaa");
  if (
     (document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
     (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)
  ) {
     if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
     } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
     } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
     }else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
        if (document.msFullscreenElement) {
           document.msExitFullscreen();
        } else {
         document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen(); 
        }
     }
  } else {
     if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
        document.cancelFullScreen();
     } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
     } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
     }
  }
}
$(".toggle-fullscreen").click(function() {
      console.log("bbbbb");
      toggleFullScreen();
   });
```

but when i click on the link of fullscreen button at that time not able to execute function written in js file.

this is just example i have so many other features written in plugins.js file.

any idea how can i make it work?

Comment: why use jquery for this ? do you have jquery added to your project ? you can just use javascript

Comment: I have purchased html template for admin panel and i am trying to implement this template in angular so i have added jquery.js file in my angular.json

Comment: Import the JS files directly in your index.html file. This will resolve the issue. I'm not sure why this happens, but it has happened to me earlier.

Comment: @SanjayAchar tried but Not working